# Showing results from Drupal Batch API

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I'm using the Drupal Batch API (https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!form.inc/group/batch/7) to perform a series of tasks. After completing the tasks, I would like the user to see a results from each task in a table (similar to the system status table).

The `finished` method has the results, however, it doesn't appear to be a way to pass that data on to the page rendering.

Comment: The only example I can think of that in core is /update.php. It just uses the session to transfer the results over from the batch completion function, that's probably your best bet

Comment: Only way I could figure out how to do it. Not the best, but not horrible; best solution available.